# Is there a plugin that does color HTML matching tags like rainbow delimiters?

Tags: html, highlighting

I would like some plugin which colors html tags with a corresponding color based on which tag they match. For example

`<div> <p></p></div>`

`<div>` and `</div>` would be highlighted the same color while `<p>` and `</p>` would be highlighted the same color, but differently than the div tags. It wouldn't be based off of what type of tag it is, just what depth it is.

Comment: In bbcode-mode (https://github.com/ejmr/bbcode-mode) something similar is done for BBcode tags like `[b][/b]` and `[url][/url]` (although not really recursive). If you feel like programming it yourself you could have a look there.

Comment: Consider report a bug to [web-mode](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues).

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for but it solves a similar problem.

The [highlight-indentation](https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs) package greatly improves my ability to see how opening/closing tags match up when editing *ml languages.

It will draw a vertical bar at every other indentation line, which will line up under a opening/closing pair if indented properly.